# SQL Server - How to combine columns with same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have somehow joined up some tables and got some columns out so when I run `SELECT SSN, Name, Year2010/Season1, Year2010/Season2, Year2010/Season3, Year2010/Season4 FROM (SELECT ...... ) AS WORKERS` I get a table showen as below:

```
SSN  Name Year2010/Season1  Year2010/Season2  Year2010/Season3  Year2010/Season4
112  John         5.4  
234  Tom                          4.2
543  Ben                                                           9.3
234  Tom                                            3.2
```

The table is showing the workers and the hours they work at each year and period. However I am trying to combine those duplicate values (same person) and move all the hours into same row depending on the year and season. Something like this (where Tom is moved):

```
SSN  Name Year2010/Season1  Year2010/Season2  Year2010/Season3  Year2010/Season4
112  John         5.4                                
234  Tom                          4.2                3.2
543  Ben                                                           9.3
```

I have been trying for hours but don't really find a good way to combine these depending on the select statement I am doing to get this table.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to use `SUM`:

```
SELECT  SSN,
        Name, 
        SUM([Year2010/Season1]) [Year2010/Season1],
        SUM([Year2010/Season2]) [Year2010/Season2],
        SUM([Year2010/Season3]) [Year2010/Season3],
        SUM([Year2010/Season4]) [Year2010/Season4]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY SSN,
         Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I forgot to mention the values of hours are set as VARCHAR. However I used this method and changed the `SUM` to `MAX` and it seems to work.

Comment: Is there any way to order the values by SSN?

Answer (score 2):

You want aggregation.  You might be able to do this more simply by adjusting your query, but you can also do:

```
with q as (<your query here>)
select ssn, name,
       max([Year2010/Season1]) as  [Year2010/Season1],
       max([Year2010/Season2]) as  [Year2010/Season2],
       max([Year2010/Season3]) as  [Year2010/Season3],
       max([Year2010/Season4]) as  [Year2010/Season4]
from q
group by ssn, name;
```

Comment: What happens if there are multiple rows for an employee with values during the same time period?